# How do I retrieve deleted bookmarks in chromium?

Tags: chromium, bookmarks

Using Chromium on two computers. One Ubuntu Precise the other Windows XP.
Bookmarks deleted on the XP and only realised it also affected my personal laptop with Ubuntu.

How do I retrieve my bookmarks in Chromium on my Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: To close-voters: This question is **not off-topic**. Bookmarks were deleted on a non-Ubuntu machine and when the Chrome profile was synced to the Ubuntu machine, they disappeared from Chromium in Ubuntu. The question is how to get them back in Ubuntu. This pertains to Ubuntu, and really has nothing to do with Windows.

Comment: Whoops! As I read from multiple trustful sources, Chromium seems to keep only 1 backup of your bookmarks and overwrite it each time it starts. I guess you've restarted chromium at least once?

Comment: This is an expected behaviour. 
See [this page](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sync) for more info. It includes several points, the essential one for this situation is quoted here:
"Changes the user makes in one client should be immediately reflected in other clients connected to the server."